# enforcing common initilisation steps to an abstract method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm currently refactoring a set of class that could be simplified as follows:

```
public abstract class A {
    public abstract Output doStuff(Input in);
}

public class B extends A {
    public Output doStuff(Input in) {
        // dostuff and return an output
    }
}
```

Now, I'd like to add a field in `A` whose value is derived from `Input in`, preferably without changing anything in the subclasses (there are around 20 classes like `B`)

Basically I'd like to find a way to call that `init` method (see bellow) at every call from `doStuff()`, without having to implement the method in class `A`, nor changing things in class extending A.

Do you know any elegant ways to do this ?

```
public abstract class A {
    private Object property;

    public abstract Output doStuff(Input in);

    private init(Input in){
      property=in.getProperty();   
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public Output doStuff(Input in) {
        // dostuff and return an output
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a restriction that you cannot change `A`?

Comment: I can change A, I wrote that I would prefer not to change classes inheriting from A, though it's more a preference than a restriction

Comment: An obvious solution would be to implement doStuff in A so that it calls init and return whatever, then change B classes to call super(in) before doing their stuff. 

But I find it ugly, hence the question

Comment: If you don't want to change subclasses, then it's too late to introduce this using pure oop. You might want to look into stunts like AOP.

Comment: as I said, it's more of a preference than anything. If a solution involving changing subclasses would prove itself elegant, i'd gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write a method in `A` which calls the `init()` method and the `doStuff()` method. That way the `init()` method gets called for every sub class automatically.

```
public abstract class A {
    private Object property;

    public Output doStuffWithInit(Input in) {
         this.init(in);
         return this.doStuff(in);
    }

    public abstract Output doStuff(Input in);

    private init(Input in){
      property=in.getProperty();   
    } 
}
```

The consuming classes has to be changed to call `doStuffWithInit()` instead to make sure that `init()` is called everytime.

Comment: Yep, thought of that too. yet there's also a bunch of consuming classes so I'd have prefer  not to do that split. I'd go for that solution if there's no new fancy  ways to do things in newer versions of java. Thanks for the answer, I'll wait a bit before accepting it :-)

Comment: Now this is going to break existing clients that called `doStuff()` directly on subclass-typed instances.